# Leaf Aptus 65S Digital Back for 645 to RZ67

Tags: medium-format, mamiya

For a somewhat cheap price I got my hands on an second hand Leaf Aptus 65S digital back, however I found out that it's for Mamiya 645.

Is there a way to replace the Adapter to use it on a RZ67? I couldn't find anything helpful. Does Aptus still provide support and exchange of the connection, or are there Adapters available?

Comment: You say replace the adapter. What adapter do you have on it already? IIRC there are two adapters available to use 645 65s on the RZ. Also, you didn't say which RZ you have.

Comment: @blobbymcblobby My camera is a RZ67 Pro II, and the digital back is for 645 AFD 3.

Comment: For PROII (non D), for an M mount (M means Mamiya 645 AFD1-3 and Phase One DF) you have two options: Mamiya HX705 adapter: can be used with any Leaf back in M mount (Aptus and Credo). This adapter requires 1 lens-to-back sync cable; or 
Leaf adapter (Leaf Mamiya RZ I/F Adapter Aptus 17/65 AFD 518-02213A): works with any Leaf Aptus M back and comes with all the cables required. (and as a complication, Mamiya HX701 adapter will work but needs modification and sync cable)

Comment: @blobbymcblobby Great, thank you, that helped me finding some second hand adapters! Do you want to put it as an answer, so I can accept it?

Comment: Sure thing, I was holding off as I was sure someone else more authoritative would put an answer down! I'll add some links too. Glad it was helpful! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For RZ76 Pro II (non D), for an M mount (M means Mamiya 645 AFD1-3 and Phase One DF aka M645) you have two options:

- Mamiya HX705 adapter: can be used with any Leaf back in M mount (Aptus and Credo). This adapter requires 1 lens-to-back sync cable;

or

- Leaf adapter (Leaf Mamiya RZ I/F Adapter Aptus 17/65 AFD 518-02213A): works with any Leaf Aptus M back and comes with all the cables required.

and as a 3rd complication,

- Mamiya HX701 adapter will work but needs modification and sync cable. The dark slide sensor on the RZ will assume that *the adapter is the dark slide* and *will not operate*, so you have to remove a tiny bit of the adapter where the sensor hits so it thinks the *dark slide has been removed*.

I looked into doing this myself a while ago but got distracted... might still do it for my old P backs..

Useful discussion links:

https://www.getdpi.com/forum/index.php?threads/df-to-rz.34524/

https://www.getdpi.com/forum/index.php?threads/how-can-i-get-into-mfd-for-minimal-money-with-my-rz67-pro-ii.58485/

https://www.getdpi.com/forum/index.php?threads/mamiya-rz67-pro-ii-non-d-digital-back-options.59062/

https://www.getdpi.com/forum/index.php?threads/rz67-plate-hx705-hx701.67978/

https://www.linhofstudio.com/products/Digital-Adapters-for-Mamiya-RB-and-RZ

[image]

[image]

https://thomaskaranikas.com/photography/hx701-digital-back-adapter-for-rz67-pro-ii/

and there is this guy in Japan who shoots with a RZ non D and various digital backs:

https://www.youtube.com/user/RyuuzakiJulio/videos